# Javascript inside iframe not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, browser

The following JavaScript code is not running within an iframe form being loaded on a page using Internet Explorer. When the form is loaded outside of an iframe it works fine. We've narrowed down the issue to the code below, which isn't running. The code below allows the user to select the current year or a future year on the form. On IE11 and down the select box is empty but it fills in the options on Chrome and Firefox. However, it's working on Edge.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $year = new Date().getFullYear() - 2000;
            var test = '';
            if(test > 2000)
                test = test - 2000;
            for(var i =0;i<10;i++) {
                var selected = "";
                    if(test == '') {
                        if(i == 2)
                        selected = "selected";
                    } else {
                        if(i+$year == test)
                            selected = "selected";
                    }
                document.write("<option value='"+(i+$year)+"' "+ selected +">"+ (i+$year) +"</option>");
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have slighty re-written your code for clarity.  You probably want to check the variable **test** and what if anything it should be doing.

You code seems to work fine in IE11 with the caveat that if you are testing this locally, then IE is likely warning you about and preventing scripts from running locally.

This is also not really the way you want to add items to you select (via **write**) but I guess it technically works :-)

```
<select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var $year = new Date().getFullYear() - 2000;
  var test = '';

  if(test > 2000) {
    // This never happens
    test = test - 2000;
  }

  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var selected = "";

    if(test == '') {
      // This always happens as test is ''
      if(i == 2) { selected = "selected"; }
    } else {
      // This never happens
      if(i+$year == test) { selected = "selected"; }
    }

    document.write("<option value='"+(i+$year)+"' "+ selected +">"+ (i+$year) +"</option>");
  }
  </script>
</select>
```